# How to change visibility of button in custom listview item layout

Tags: android, android-listview

I have listview with custom layout, each layout has one TextView, one Seekbar and one Button. All I want to do is when I click the Edit button, all buttons inside custom layout become visible. I use notifyDataSetChanged after click the edit button, nothing was changed.

Here my code snippets.

In CustomAdapter I define one method, boolean flag and getView method;

```
public class NavigationDrawerListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  boolean editmode = false;

  @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
    holder.mButton=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    holder.mButton.setVisibility( (editmode ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE ) );
  }
}


}



public void setEditMode(boolean value){
            editmode = value;
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

My ListViewActivity Class;

```
editLayers = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.editLayersButton);
editLayers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editLayers.getText().equals("Düzenle")) {
                    myAdapter.setEditMode(true);
                    editLayers.setText("Tamam");


                } else {
                    myAdapter.setEditMode(false);
                    editLayers.setText("Düzenle");



                }


            }


        });
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Need the else code for "if (convertView == null)". The reason is convertView may not be null because it is recycled.

Comment: It seems you have a solution already but I noticed there is a bug on the posted code. So I posted an answer, hopefully it will be useful and avoid intermittent issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
if (convertView == null) {
    holder.mButton=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
convertView.setTag(holder);
  }else{
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

And then write. Move the following code outside of `if.. else...`

```
 holder.mButton.setVisibility( (editmode ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE ) );
```

Comment: In order to show short code snippets, I didn't paste else section of 'if'

Comment: I didn't understand ? What you mean?

Comment: Did you move this  holder.mButton.setVisibility( (editmode ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE ) ); outside of if.. else?

Comment: I move now :) and  worked like a charm ^^ Ovv my mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: Always welcome.Then accept the answer. And close this.

Comment: SO say that you can accept this answer after 7 minute. I'll check your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in `getView()`, need to create an instance for object `holder`.

Suggested code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       ...
    }
```

Notice `holder = new`.